# Tic tac toe js is not responding

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe

Ok so I just copied this code for Tic tac toe game and tried running it on my pc but it wasn't displaying wins.

Here's the js code thats really the bone of contention. The calls that check for three straight wins which reflects as green is not working. The markers still remain their normal black colour and worst still the game goes on without saying who won.

```js
var turn = 1
$('button').click(function() {
  if (turn == 1) {
    $("#screen").text("Player Two Turn Follows");

    $(this).addClass("fa fa-check");
    turn = 2;
  } else {
    $("#screen").text("Player One Turn Follows");

    $(this).addClass("fa fa-times");
    turn = 1;
  }
});
$("button").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("fa fa-times") ||
    $(this).hasClass("fa fa-check")) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    setTimeout(() => {
      $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    }, 800);
  }
});

function check(symbol) {
  if ($(".sq1").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq2").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq3").hasClass(symbol)) {
    $(".sq1").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq2").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq3").css("color", "green");
    return true;
  } else if ($(".sq4").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq5").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq6").hasClass(symbol)) {
    $(".sq4").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq5").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq6").css("color", "green");
    return true;
  } else if ($(".sq7").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq8").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq9").hasClass(symbol)) {
    $(".sq7").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq8").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq9").css("color", "green");
    return true;
  } else if ($(".sq1").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq4").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq7").hasClass(symbol)) {
    $(".sq1").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq4").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq7").css("color", "green");
    return true;
  } else if ($(".sq2").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq5").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq8").hasClass(symbol)) {
    $(".sq2").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq5").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq8").css("color", "green");
    return true;
  } else if ($(".sq3").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq6").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq9").hasClass(symbol)) {
    $(".sq3").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq6").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq9").css("color", "green");
    return true;
  } else if ($(".sq1").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq5").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq9").hasClass(symbol)) {
    $(".sq1").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq5").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq9").css("color", "green");
    return true;
  } else if ($(".sq3").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq5").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq7").hasClass(symbol)) {
    $(".sq3").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq5").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq7").css("color", "green");
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function reset() {
  $("#screen").text("PLAYER 1 TURN FOLLOWS");
  $("#screen").css("background-color", "transparent");
  $(".r").removeClass("fa fa-check");
  $(".r").removeClass("fa fa-times");
  turn = 1;

  $(".sq1").css("color", "black");
  $(".sq2").css("color", "black");
  $(".sq3").css("color", "black");
  $(".sq4").css("color", "black");
  $(".sq5").css("color", "black");
  $(".sq6").css("color", "black");
  $(".sq7").css("color", "black");
  $(".sq8").css("color", "black");
  $(".sq9").css("color", "black");

}
```

```css
td {
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid black;
  font-size: 100px
}

button {
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  border: 0px transparent;
  border-radius: 2%;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
}

#b {
  height: 50px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Tic-tac-toe.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!</h1>
      <p>
        Get ready to play!
      </p>
      <!-- <button id="b" class="btn btn-success btn-lag" type="button" name="button" onclick="reset()">Restart!</button> -->
      <input id="b" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lag" value="Restart!" onClick="reset()" />
    </div>
    <div class="container-fliud text-center">
      <h4 id="screen">Player One Turn Follows</h4>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <table align="center">
        <tr>
          <td><button class="sq1 r"></button></td>
          <td><button class="sq2 r"></button></td>
          <td><button class="sq3 r"></button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button class="sq4 r"></button></td>
          <td><button class="sq5 r"></button></td>
          <td><button class="sq6 r"></button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button class="sq7 r"></button></td>
          <td><button class="sq8 r"></button></td>
          <td><button class="sq9 r"></button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  </div>
</body>
<script src="Tic-tac-toe.js"></script>

</html>
```

I want to be able to output a winning statement that says player one or player two you win.

Thanks I'll really appreciate the help

Comment: Where do you call `check()`?

Comment: You're loading two copies of jQuery. Don't do that.

Comment: Where can I call it? It's actually not called

Comment: Oops deleted one of the extra copy of jQuery

Comment: You should call it when the user clicks on a table cell, after setting the class based on which player has clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `check()` after each user plays. I've added another value for `turn`. When it's `0`, the game is over and no plays can be made.

I also added a check for all the cells being filled in, which means it's a draw if someone didn't already win.

```js
var turn = 1

$('button').click(function() {
  if (turn == 1) {
    $("#screen").text("Player Two Turn Follows");

    $(this).addClass("fa fa-check");
    if (check('fa-check')) {
      turn = 0;
      $("#screen").text("Player One Wins!");
    } else {
      turn = 2;
    }
  } else if (turn == 2) {
    $("#screen").text("Player One Turn Follows");

    $(this).addClass("fa fa-times");
    if (check('fa-times')) {
      turn = 0;
      $("#screen").text("Player Two Wins!");
    } else {
      turn = 1;
    }
  }
  if (turn != 0 && $("button.fa").length == 9) {
    turn = 0;
    $("#screen").text("It's a draw!");
  }
});
$("button").click(function() {
  if (turn == 0) {
    return;
  }
  if ($(this).hasClass("fa fa-times") ||
    $(this).hasClass("fa fa-check")) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    setTimeout(() => {
      $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    }, 800);
  }
});

function check(symbol) {
  if ($(".sq1").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq2").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq3").hasClass(symbol)) {
    $(".sq1").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq2").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq3").css("color", "green");
    return true;
  } else if ($(".sq4").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq5").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq6").hasClass(symbol)) {
    $(".sq4").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq5").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq6").css("color", "green");
    return true;
  } else if ($(".sq7").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq8").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq9").hasClass(symbol)) {
    $(".sq7").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq8").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq9").css("color", "green");
    return true;
  } else if ($(".sq1").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq4").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq7").hasClass(symbol)) {
    $(".sq1").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq4").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq7").css("color", "green");
    return true;
  } else if ($(".sq2").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq5").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq8").hasClass(symbol)) {
    $(".sq2").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq5").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq8").css("color", "green");
    return true;
  } else if ($(".sq3").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq6").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq9").hasClass(symbol)) {
    $(".sq3").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq6").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq9").css("color", "green");
    return true;
  } else if ($(".sq1").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq5").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq9").hasClass(symbol)) {
    $(".sq1").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq5").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq9").css("color", "green");
    return true;
  } else if ($(".sq3").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq5").hasClass(symbol) &&
    $(".sq7").hasClass(symbol)) {
    $(".sq3").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq5").css("color", "green");
    $(".sq7").css("color", "green");
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function reset() {
  $("#screen").text("PLAYER 1 TURN FOLLOWS");
  $("#screen").css("background-color", "transparent");
  $(".r").removeClass("fa fa-check");
  $(".r").removeClass("fa fa-times");
  turn = 1;

  $(".sq1").css("color", "black");
  $(".sq2").css("color", "black");
  $(".sq3").css("color", "black");
  $(".sq4").css("color", "black");
  $(".sq5").css("color", "black");
  $(".sq6").css("color", "black");
  $(".sq7").css("color", "black");
  $(".sq8").css("color", "black");
  $(".sq9").css("color", "black");

}
```

```css
td {
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid black;
  font-size: 100px
}

button {
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  border: 0px transparent;
  border-radius: 2%;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
}

#b {
  height: 50px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Tic-tac-toe.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!</h1>
      <p>
        Get ready to play!
      </p>
      <!-- <button id="b" class="btn btn-success btn-lag" type="button" name="button" onclick="reset()">Restart!</button> -->
      <input id="b" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lag" value="Restart!" onClick="reset()" />
    </div>
    <div class="container-fliud text-center">
      <h4 id="screen">Player One Turn Follows</h4>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <table align="center">
        <tr>
          <td><button class="sq1 r"></button></td>
          <td><button class="sq2 r"></button></td>
          <td><button class="sq3 r"></button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button class="sq4 r"></button></td>
          <td><button class="sq5 r"></button></td>
          <td><button class="sq6 r"></button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button class="sq7 r"></button></td>
          <td><button class="sq8 r"></button></td>
          <td><button class="sq9 r"></button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  </div>
</body>
<script src="Tic-tac-toe.js"></script>

</html>
```